# How to draw a diagram using powershell using a list

Tags: javascript, powershell

I am going to try and create a diagram that demonstrates api dependencies based on urls in source control.  To do this I am using powershell to clone all the repo's in github and then loop through the files that have the relevant information in the Web Config and appsettings files.  By doing this I think the best approach for me is to get the name of the repo:

```
Write-Host "Repo: "$repo.name
```

And then I loop through the web config's to get a list.

```
$WebReleaseConfig = "Web.Release.config"

foreach($repo in $repos) { 
    $repo
    $name = $repo.Name
    $path = C:\Users\cd\ApiDependencies\$name

    if(Test-Path -Path C:\Users\cd\ApiDependencies) {
        $config = Get-ChildItem -Path $WebReleaseConfig -Recurse
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content $config

        $xmlList = @()
        $xmlList = $xmlList +
                   ($xml.SelectNodes('//add').Value -like '*.co.uk*') +
                   ($xml.SelectNodes('//add').Value -like '*.com/*')

        Write-Host "The List contains"
        $xmlList     
    }
}
```

This list will contain information like this:

```
http://applications.c
http://auth.c
https://clearscore.c.co.uk/
```

The problem I have is that this list is going to overwrite as there are multiple projects and I will need to create a diagram from this information anyway so I think it would be best to create a diagram that will draw an arrow from the repo name to each item in the list.  This would then update the diagram every repo that is added and some repo's will also have arrows going to the same items in their own list.  I have tried out Mermaid docs and so Javascript but this doesn't like a good way to do this as I am overwriting data and it seems to be more used to hard code data. How can I do this properly?

Output would look like :

```
 a --> 1
 a --> 2
 a --> 3
 b --> 2
 b --> 4
 c --> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what kind of output you're expecting. But for what you want as the final output, I think you need to output something like

```
projectA-->projectB
projectA-->projectJ
projectB-->projectD 
....
```

My suggestion would be to use ImageMagic's display utility. You can see how this is used in the one-liner:

```
lsmod | awk 'BEGIN{print "digraph{"}{split($4, a, ","); for (i in a) print $1, "->", a[i]}END{print "}"}'|display
```

Yes, it is unix shell scripting, but the idea is to write something like:

```
digraph{
    node1 -> node2
    node1 -> node3
    node2 -> node6
}
```

Then let display do the rest of the work

Comment: it would be like `a --> 1, a --> 2, a --> 3, b --> 2, b --> 4, c --> 1` etc.